# mysql syntax in clause

Tags: mysql, sql

im using mysql and was wondering about its syntax.

i want to make an IN clause something like this:

```
from_id OR to_id IN (
)
```

except i dont know how the syntax is

i want to avoid running the in clause twice like this:

```
from_id IN (
)

OR

to_id IN (
)
```

best of regards
alexander

Comment: For the most part, you don't really need to worry about "running the in clause twice" like that because most dbms's cache the data / hold it temporarily when being used so it isn't necessarily "twice the effort".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some reasons to worry about the IN clause being run twice (for example, if the subquery is particularly complex and the optimiser doesn't seem to have taken advantage of caching the result set), you can always replace the IN clause with INNER JOIN.

So this:

```
FROM x
WHERE from_id IN (
  subquery
)
OR
to_id IN (
  subquery
)
```

becomes this:

```
FROM x
  INNER JOIN (
    subquery
  ) y ON y.value IN (x.from_id, x.to_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Only the second form is valid.

As @judda mentions, don't worry about premature optimization. The query optimizer will take advantage of caching where possible.