# Query on multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
dd_set

id     dd_id
1037    19
1037    5
1037    20
1037    3
1037    7
1038   1
1038   7
```

i want to find find id where dd_id=19 and dd_id =5 and dd_id=20

is this possible to do in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql syntax in clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785785/mysql-syntax-in-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be

```
select id from dd_set
where dd_id in (19,5,20)
group by id
having count(distinct dd_id) = 3
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM dd_set 
WHERE dd_id IN(19,5,20);
```